# Symfony OAuth2 with Keycloak returns invalid_token: Token verification failed

Tags: php, symfony, docker-compose, oauth-2.0

### Goal

I'm trying to setup OAuth2 in Symfony 6 with Keycloak and the libraries [knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle/issues) and [stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak). Everything is setup with `docker compose (v2.2)` and I'm using `Traefik (v2.5)` as proxy.

### Problem

When trying to validate the user, after going to `/connect/keycloak`, succesfully getting redirected to `https://keycloak.example.local/auth/realms/.../protocol/openid-connect/auth`, logging in succesfully and redirected back to `/connect/keycloak/check`, I keep getting the error that the token verification failed.

```
IdentityProviderException
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
invalid_token: Token verification failed
```

[image]

Further inspection of the underlying guzzle response shows a `401` statusCode with the `WWW-Authenticate` header showing the error:

```
"Bearer realm="redacted", error="invalid_token", error_description="Token verification failed"
```

### Application

I've setup the following in my Symfony 6 (PHP 8.1) app:

`config\packages\framework.yaml`

```yaml
  session:
    enabled: true
    handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax
```

`config\packages\knpu_oauth2_client.yaml`

```yaml
knpu_oauth2_client:
  http_client_options:
    timeout: 0
    proxy: 'http://keycloak:8080'
    verify: false
  clients:
    keycloak:
      type: keycloak
      client_id: '%env(OAUTH_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID)%'
      client_secret: '%env(OAUTH_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET)%'
      redirect_route: '%env(OAUTH_KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_ROUTE)%'
      redirect_params: { }
      auth_server_url: '%env(OAUTH_KEYCLOAK_URL)%'
      realm: '%env(OAUTH_KEYCLOAK_REALM)%'
```

`config\packages\security.yaml`

```yaml
...
  providers:
    oauth:
      id: knpu.oauth2.user_provider
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: oauth
      custom_authenticator: App\Security\KeycloakAuthenticator
```

`App\Controller\KeycloakController`

```php
namespace App\Controller;

use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class KeycloakController
 */
final class KeycloakController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/connect/keycloak', name: 'connect_keycloak_start')]
    public function connectAction(
        ClientRegistry $clientRegistry
    ): RedirectResponse {
        return $clientRegistry->getClient('keycloak')->redirect(['email'], []);
    }

    #[Route('/connect/keycloak/check', name: 'connect_keycloak_check')]
    public function connectCheckAction(
        Request $request,
        ClientRegistry $clientRegistry
    ) {
    }
}
```

`App\Security\KeycloakAuthenticator`

```php
namespace App\Security;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\Provider\KeycloakClient;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\OAuth2Authenticator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\SelfValidatingPassport;

/**
 * Class KeycloakAuthenticator
 */
class KeycloakAuthenticator extends OAuth2Authenticator
{
    private $clientRegistry;
    private $entityManager;
    private $router;

    /**
     * KeycloakAuthenticator constructor.
     * @param  ClientRegistry  $clientRegistry
     * @param  EntityManagerInterface  $em
     * @param  RouterInterface  $router
     */
    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, EntityManagerInterface $em, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->entityManager = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'connect_keycloak_check';
    }

    /**
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Passport
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        /** @var KeycloakClient $client */
        $client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('keycloak');
        $accessToken = $this->fetchAccessToken($client);

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge($accessToken->getToken(), function () use ($accessToken, $client) {
                return $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken);
            })
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  TokenInterface  $token
     * @param  string  $firewallName
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

### Docker Compose

`docker-compose.yml - app`

```yaml
  phpfpm:
    build:
      context: docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
    container_name: app_phpfpm
    user: ${UID}:${GID}
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PHP_OPCACHE_ENABLE=${OPCACHE_ENABLE}
      - PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS=${OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS}
      - PHP_OPCACHE_PRELOAD_ENV=${APP_ENV}
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ~/certs:/certs
      - ./docker/php/conf/opcache.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini
      - ./docker/php/conf/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
      - ./docker/php/conf/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.${APP_DOMAIN}.conf
    networks:
      - proxy
      - app-network

  apache:
    build:
      context: docker/apache
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        APACHE_VERSION: ${APACHE_VERSION}
    container_name: app_apache
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - apache_log:/var/log/apache2
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${APP_NAME}-apache-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${APP_NAME}-apache-secure.rule=Host(`${APP_DOMAIN}`, `www.${APP_DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${APP_NAME}-apache-secure.service=${APP_NAME}-apache-service"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${APP_NAME}-apache-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${APP_NAME}-apache-secure.middlewares=secure-headers@file"
      - "traefik.http.services.${APP_NAME}-apache-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
    networks:
      - proxy
      - app-network
```

`docker-compose.yml - keycloak (16.1.0)`

```yaml
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION}
    container_name: keycloak
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-postgres
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: keycloak_postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: ${KEYCLOAK_STORAGE_POSTGRES_DATABASE}
      DB_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_STORAGE_POSTGRES_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_STORAGE_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_USERNAME}
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME: keycloak.${APP_DOMAIN}
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-secure.rule=Host(`keycloak.${APP_DOMAIN}`, `www.keycloak.${APP_DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-secure.service=keycloak-service"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak-service.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
    networks:
      - proxy
      - keycloak-network
```

`docker-compose.yml - traefik (2.5)`

```yaml
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v${TRAEFIK_VERSION}
    container_name: traefik
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
    environment:
      CF_API_EMAIL: ${CF_EMAIL}
      CF_API_KEY: ${CF_API_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ./docker/traefik/config/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./docker/traefik/config/dynamic:/dynamic:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /usr/share/zoneinfo:/usr/share/zoneinfo:ro
      - ~/certs:/certs
    networks:
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.${APP_DOMAIN}`, `www.traefik.${APP_DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
```

`traefik.yml`

```yaml
api:
  dashboard: true

log:
  format: json
  level: DEBUG

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: websecure

  websecure:
    address: :443

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
    watch: true
    network: proxy
  file:
    directory: /dynamic
    watch: true
```

`dynamic/http.yml`

```yaml
http:
  middlewares:
    secure-headers:
      headers:
        frameDeny: true
        browserXssFilter: true
        contentTypeNosniff: true
        forceSTSHeader: true
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
        stsPreload: true
        stsSeconds: 63072000
        customFrameOptionsValue: SAMEORIGIN
        referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
        customRequestHeaders:
          X-Forwarded-Proto: https
          X-Robots-Tag: "none,noarchive,nosnippet,notranslate,noimageindex,"
```

with `proxy` set as external network.

### Keycloak

I've setup the client as follows and configured the `Credentials` with basic `Client Id and Secret` (no signed JWT).

[image]

When checking the events, only thing that seems different is that the first the IP address being used. The `LOGIN` action uses the client IP, whereas the `CODE_TO_TOKEN` action uses the IP of the docker container.
[image]

No idea if this is related to the token verification failing.

Also the sessions seems to get set correctly with the user ip.
[image: session started]

### Debug

After trying to debug the authentication progress, I noticed that the `access_token` that is returned after login, is the same as the one being used to get the users info. So it hasn't changed or anything (which I could image causing the error).

It's already been 3 days of (trying) to debug this but I'm just getting nowhere. Seems there are literally no similar cases to be found which could help me debug this further. I don't know if I'm missing something obvious, but I'm out of ideas now. Any bit of help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Looks like I have same problem

Comment: @VolodymyrI. Sadly no. I've asked the question in Keycloak's [github repo](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/9820) as well but didn't get a response there. I've got a response when asked it on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-user/c/NtAkE5SE0vo/m/VRAK9ju_BAAJ), but I haven't invested more time in trying to fix this.

Comment: For those interested, I eventually swapped Keycloak for [Authentik](https://goauthentik.io/), which I found much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Maybe this helps you, too: https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak/issues/43#issuecomment-1066598308

Seems to be a problem with the "issuer" inside the token.

Comment: This actually pointed me to the solution: my problem was using `localhost` as keycloak base url (set in HWIOauthBundle as base_url param, used to redirect the user to keycloak login page in the browser), but using `host.docker.internal` domain for symfony app <> keycloak communication. Must be related to including the domain in token validation. Thank you Sir!